# Alamofire.upload - Response Handler not called

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

When using Alamofire to upload Data to my Server, the Response-Handler is not called!

I Can see the document hast been uploaded in the server logs and also can see the response in Wireshark!

Any ideas?

My Code:

```
Alamofire.upload(document.content, to: url, method: .put, headers: headers).responseJSON { response in
        print(response)
    }
```

- Alamofire-Version: 4.8.1
- iOS-Version: 12.0
- XCode-Version: 10.1
- Mac OS-Version : 10.14
- Swift-Version: 4.2

Comment: try with `response { (dataResponse) in
            debugPrint(dataResponse.response) }` instead of `responseJSON`

Comment: Thanks Rocky, unfortunately it has the same effect as responseJson -> None ( Also tried responseString)

Comment: If the server is not sending any response after receiving the document, your response callback won't get called. Try if you are getting progress callbacks. Check the server if it is sending a response after receiving the file.

Comment: @kerry as mentioned i can see the response in my network sniffer (wireshark) also it worked in the previous version with “HttpRequestSynch”

Comment: check with `dataResponse.request`

Comment: @Rocky can you elaborate how to use this?

Comment: `debugPrint(dataResponse.request)  debugPrint(dataResponse.response?.statusCode)`

Comment: What is document.content ?

Comment: @PrashantTukadiya a JSON as Data